# Connect to host and run ps aux command

Tags: python, linux

Trying to ssh to Ubuntu and get process details. Can connect and login to device, but unable to get output. Getting output as below,

connected to device x.x.x.x
1
('Command: ', 'ps aux | grep vmstat')
2
Did not connect to x.x.x.x

```
import os
import paramiko
import time
import signal
import subprocess

processname = 'vmstat'

def connect_to_devices(ip, procname):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        ssh.connect(ip, username = 'xxxxx', password='xxxxx', timeout = 10)
        time.sleep(.25)
        channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
        output = channel.recv(10000)
        print(output)
        print("connected to device")
        proc = findprocess(procname)
        time.sleep(10)
        print('2')
        print(proc)
        return proc

    except:
        print("Did not connect to %s" % ip)
        return 'failed'

def findprocess(p):
    print('1')
    command = 'ps aux | grep ' + processname
    print('Command: ', command)
    print('2')
    for line in os.popen(command,'r',1):
        print('3')
        fields = line.split()
        print('4')
    print (fields)
    return fields

hosts = ['x.x.x.x']
for h in hosts:
    t = connect_to_devices(h, processname)
```

Comment: Some Exception occurred in `findprocess`. Please add `traceback.print_exc()` after except to display the full exception. Remember to import traceback.

Comment: No Working: Still same output. From trace, it's not hitting for-loop, 'for line in os.popen(command,'r',1)'

Comment: You should paste the exception printed otherwise I don't know how to help you.